# Trouble separating MySqlConnection, MySqlCommand, etc. into another class because of query strings

Tags: c#

```
public void addEmployee(string fname, string lname)
{
    string addQuery = "INSERT INTO emp_table (emp_fname, emp_lname) VALUES (@fname, @lname)";

    MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connectionString"]);
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(addQuery, connection);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", fname);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lname", lname);

    connection.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    connection.Close();
}
```

I want to put the lines MySqlConnection and MySqlCommand to the Connection class but the MySqlCommand has "addQuery" parameter. the reason i want it to avoid repeating the initialization of connection and command. so i dont have to call connection and cmd repeatedly.

Comment: You could create a `Connection` class that can set up and maintain the `MySqlConnection` internally.  It could have a public `CreateCommand` function that returns a `MySqlCommand` for you to populate.What you really should be looking in to though, is the "Repository" pattern.  If you design your data access  around that model, you should be in good shape for the future.

Comment: encapsulate different codes into delegate (Func or Action), then create a new method contains the shared code and using the delegate as a parameter.

Comment: You can move `MySqlConnection` object in `Program` class and make it `public static`. Then initialize it once and open once for the entire session after User Login until logout or close app. This is in case of desktop application.

Comment: @i486 If `MySqlConnection` works like `SqlConnection`, that is a *very* bad idea.

Comment: @BradleyUffner Why? The idea is to keep open connection for the entire session, not to open it for each query.

Comment: @i486 Connection Pooling makes having a connection per operation a better choice.  If you have one connection for the life of the application, you won't be taking advantage of that.  One connection also limits the number of simultaneous readers you can have.

Comment: @BradleyUffner What about SQL Management Studio or other tools like it? Are they stupid to keep open connection or they are special software? Connection Pooling is necessary for web applications/services where keeping open connection is technically impossible. I comment the case with desktop application.

Comment: @i486 SSMS does not keep a single connection open for the life of the application. It manages connections to multiple servers at once, with multiple connections per server.  Those connections can be opened and closed dynamically.

Comment: @i486 -- "The idea is to keep open connection for the entire session, not to open it for each query."  -- that's entirely wrong.  The idea is to keep a connection open for as short a period as possible, basically open it at the start of a transaction and close it at the end.  What you're proposing can lead to locking issues that can prevent entire user-bases from using applications.  I know from experience:

Comment: @i486 One time I threw together some code to perform a blanket operation on one of our enterprise databases.  Unfortunately, it was going to affect millions of records and take an hour or so to complete, so I went to the gym.  I came back from the gym and the whole firm and IT department was in crisis mode because no one could use the document management system software, which, for a law firm, is very bad news.  I stopped my code and it fixed the problem right away.

Comment: @i486 it was because I had designed the hastily-thrown-together app poorly and kept the connection open for an hour or two, performing business logic operations within each loop through the recordset, locking rows in the db here and there.  Bad news.

Comment: @rory.ap Obviously your query has been wrong and locked tables or rows. Please explain me what will help in this case the dynamically re-opened connections instead of keeping single connection - your problem were with long running query. It will not become faster with connection pooling. You have bad DB/query design, not something else.

Comment: @i486 -- it's always better to design robust code, to err on the side of caution.  The practice of keeping a db connection open is just wrong.  You want to close/dispose so the connection is returned to the pool; let .NET manage the connection pool.  A connection that is explicitly left open does not return to the pool, and thus you are holding resources unnecessarily.  Open connection, begin tran, run your query, get your results, commit tran, close connection.

Comment: @rory.ap Depends on type of software. Imagine that you have sales DB. Multiple terminals (10-20, not 1000) are connected all time and do intensive sales. Do you still think that closing connections is better solution than keeping open all time?

Comment: @i486 -- The connection pool doesn't really "close" the connections; it keeps them alive but does so in an as efficient a way as possible.  It can't do that if you explicitly keep the connections open.  Don't go against the way it was designed to work; just go with the flow.

Comment: @rory.ap "the flow" is for mass of web applications and services. Don't think that SQL is designed to work with temporary connections - connection pooling is only solution for such cases. I can say: think, don't go blindly with the flock.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should always have a distinct connection and command for each query.  However, you can achieve some re-usability: I'd recommend creating a database service class that takes a query and a collection of parameters and executes the query.  In fact, you could combine the function of a query that doesn't return rows with one that does, because you will just get an empty dataset for the former:

```
internal static class MySqlDataManager
{
    internal static System.Data.DataSet GetMySqlDataSet(string usingQuery,
         string usingConnectionString, params MySqlParameter[] withParameters)
    {
        using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(usingConnectionString))
        using (var command = new MySqlCommand(usingQuery, conn))
        {
            command.Parameters.AddRange(withParameters);
            var ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
            using (var adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(command)) adapter.Fill(ds);
            return ds;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: honestly, the answer was too complex for me. i cannot read or imagine how that code does (for now) as i am newbie.

Comment: @RandyB. -- This code is bare bones.  It's as simple as it gets.  You should see the version with transaction-friendly connection maintenance.

Comment: Thank u. I have all the time to study this. Right now I don’t understand yet but soon I will.